# Method for determining if an object has focus

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a method for determining if an html object has focus? I know there exists document.hasFocus to determine if the document has focus, but from what I can tell, this does not extend to objects within the document (eg. I tried document.getElementById("thing").hasFocus with no success).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.activeElement` (a member, not a method).

http://jsfiddle.net/FVDdQ/